# MVVM - How ListView ItemClick Execute RelayCommand with Bindig

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, windows-8

I would like to add a command to my listview. When an item is clicked I would like to execute my relayCommand.
Now I have these solution, it works, but I think it is not so MVVM :)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Taxons}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListViewBase_OnItemClick">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void ListViewBase_OnItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
       viewModel.TreeItemSelected.Execute(((Taxon)e.ClickedItem).Name);
}
```

I would like to use this way without any code behind, but it is not possible as the VS tells me:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Taxons}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="{Binding TreeItemSelected}">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I use the following extra dll-s, but i dont want to install anything else if it possible.
GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.Win8
GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Win8

Can you suggest a solution to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working example :

```
<ListBox x:Name="name_here" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding your_item_source}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding your_selected_item, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     ...
      >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding your_command_here}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=name_here, Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

It make use of Blend's Interaction triggers (you don't have to install blend, the dll is enough if you don't have it).
also, if you're using the `CommandParameter`, bind the `ElementName` to the name of the control (in this example it's `name_here` )

Answer (score 3):

For those who have the same problem, I would like to say that there is another way:
You can define a `TapGestureRecognizer` for the **ListView** items and bind it to a command in your **ViewModel**, as I'm showing here :

```
<StackLayout x:Name="StackLayout1" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">    
   <StackLayout.BindingContext>
       <viewModels:NotificationsViewModel />
   </StackLayout.BindingContext>

   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding NotificationsList}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">  

              <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>  <!-- here you bind the TAP event to your ViewModel -->
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.OnListItemTapped, Source={x:Reference StackLayout1}}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
              </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

              <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Image x:Name="IsReadImage" StyleId="IsReadImage" WidthRequest="{StaticResource OptionImageSize}"
                       Source='{Binding IsRead, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToValueConverter}, ConverterParameter="Resources.emailOpenIcon,Resources.emailIcon"}'
                       RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}"
                       RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.8, Constant=0}"></Image>

                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" x:Name="TitleLabel" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontAttributes='{Binding IsRead, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToValueConverter}, ConverterParameter="Bold?!"}'
                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=IsReadImage, Property=Width, Constant=5}"
                       RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=IsReadImage, Property=Y, Constant=3}" /></RelativeLayout>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

And then you can define your command in the page's ViewModel

```
public ICommand OnListItemTapped
{
    get
    {
        return new Command<Notification>(item =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Title + " Cliked!");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this two ways. 
One would be to bind the list views SelectedItem to a property on your viewmodel.  (maybe call that property SelectedTaxon),  then in the property setter you could take whatever action you wish on the viewmodel.

The other way,  if you are really tied to executing a command on your viewmodel. You can use the mvvmlight EventToCommand behavior. 
You can find info about that via Google or at this link is a description of its use. http://adammills.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/eventtocommand-action-mvvm-glue/

I believe that you already have that behavior as part of the mvvmlight extras dll you have.